# The usage of slander, defame, vilify, and calumniate

Tags: differences, vocabulary

English is not my native language. I am confused about the usage of these four words: slander, defame, vilify, and calumniate.

They are all verbs with almost the same meaning and I don't have any ideas which one should I use in any situation. Are there any big differences in usage? For instance, is one more frequently used than the others? Are there any that are obsolete or not commonly used?

I am particularly interested in knowing if there are contextual differences in usage, like when someone says a bad thing to me in daily life, in business, or in any formal or informal situation. I would like to know how native English speakers use them.

Comment: If a word is obsolete, a good dictionary will tell you so.

Comment: Samuel, you may also wish to visit the stackexchange site for [**English language learners**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners). This is still under development and not yet accepting questions, but it will do so when interest reaches a critical mass.

Comment: @Luke: most dictionaries will tend to either leave out the word or indicate only the most extreme cases. Also, a dictionary doesn't do comparisons, so they won't say that calumniate is rarer and more formal than slander (but all of these words are of a fairly formal register).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *defame* by publishing information hurting good reputation - possibly embarrassing, claiming incompetence or negligence.

You *vilify* if you defame by presenting the person's actions to be evil. Posting photos of someone sleeping under a tree, drunk may be defaming. Photo of that person raising a hand on a child is vilifying. Also, presenting normally mostly benign actions, making them to appear as evil is called vilifying (e.g. claim a woman who wears a red dress is "dressing like a whore")

*Slander* is a defamation that is false. (note for a long time in England one could win a lawsuit for defamation even if the defaming claim was proven true. Slander is always a defamation which is a lie)

I'm sorry but I won't give you any details on *calumniate*, I can only guess that's not a very frequently used synonym for *slander*. I think it implies verbal (or textual) form of slander, which on itself may take other forms (performing, parodying) but don't quote me on that.

You should also note *libel* (per StoneyB's comment) which is the same a slander except committed in a fixed/permanent form - slander is always in a volatile form (speech, gestures), while libel is fixed - in writing, as a picture, video, voice recording etc.

Comment: 1.The difference between slander and defame is:  the defamation of defame can be true.But the slander always is false 2. vilify is you  writing not saying . right?

Comment: @Samuel  'Writing not saying' distinguishes *libel* from *slander*. [This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defamation) on Wikipedia discusses legal dimensions of defamation.

Comment: *Calumniate* is a very rare word, derived from *calumny*, and is basically the same as *slander*. Note that *vilify* in informal or semiformal often means little more than calling somebody rude names.

Comment: Actually I still not know when to use vilify. Can i consider that  defame is the father word of slander and vilify . Any situations can use defame.

Comment: @Samuel: Vilifying is making someone appear evil (a criminal, a murderer, a thief etc), and not merely disreputable (lazy, stupid, incompetent). Something to elicit hate and not just disrespect.

Comment: @Samuel: And yes, "Defame" is the father word, but note how defamation is not always wrong. Defaming a tyrant or a corrupt politician - bringing their evil machinations to light - is a good act! Meanwhile, slander is universally perceived as something bad.

Answer (score 3):

In some contexts, these words are interchangeable, but each has a different shade of meaning.

*Calumniate* means to falsely or maliciously accuse, especially of a crime. *Defame* and *slander* mean to spread tales about a person so as to damage their reputation, but *defame* refers more to the intended result while *slander* refers more to the action taken. *Vilify* means to make vile, generally by slandering.

See *OneLook.com* for links to many general reference works containing definitions and examples of usage.

Answer (score 1):

Slander is to defame by telling a lie. Calumny is to defame by telling what I know to be true with the intention of sullying someone's good name. In the case of calumny,the information is confidential and although it may reveal illegal or unethical behavior performed in the past, guilt or innocence has been resolved in some way or the revelation of it may produce more harm than good.